# Is there some way to display alert boxes on google colab?

Tags: html, css, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

To display nice boxes on Jupyter Notebooks, it is possible to use `alert` HTML tags and put inside some markdown content.

Here an example displayed on a `Jupyter Lab` instance :

```markdown
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="color: rgba(0,0,0,.8); background-color: white; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em; margin:1.5625emauto; padding:0 .6rem .8rem!important;overflow:hidden; page-break-inside:avoid; border-radius:.25rem; box-shadow:0 .2rem .5rem rgba(0,0,0,.05),0 0 .05rem rgba(0,0,0,.1); transition:color .25s,background-color .25s,border-color .25s ; border-right: 1px solid #dee2e6 ; border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6 ; border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6 ; border-left:.2rem solid #007bff80;">
<h3 class="alert-heading"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Note</h3>

An example of a nicely formatted box

</div>
```

[image]

This can even be simplified to basic alerts :

```markdown
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
<h3 class="alert-heading">Note</h3>

An example of a nicely formatted box

</div>
```

[image]

However, the same notebook does not render well on `Google Colab`:

[image]

Example notebook [here](https://github.com/linogaliana/python-datascientist/blob/master/notebooks/course/manipulation/02a_pandas_tutorial.ipynb)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe make your own classes. following code works both in collab and jupyter
You can use the HTML magic command to display the HTML code directly

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML("""
<div class="alert">
  <p>This is an alert box.</p>
</div>

<style>
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
</style>
""")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe as an idea, run it as snipped as a python code block:

```py
#@title Alert Notification
from IPython.display import HTML

alert_info = '''
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
  <h3 class="alert-heading">Note</h3>
  An example of a nicely formatted box
</div>
'''

display(HTML('<link href="https://nbviewer.org/static/build/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">'))
display(HTML(alert_info))
```

[image: Google Colab Preview]

Text cells are formatted using a [markdown](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/markdown_guide.ipynb) language version which is also uses at GitHub. The support for this feature on GitHub is still being [discussed](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/16925).

I use the UTF-8 icons combined with a quote block:

```
> #  Info
> This is a note.

> # ⚠ Warning
> This is a warning.

> # ⛔ Alert
> This is an alert.
```

[image: google colab source code and preview]

Answer (score 2):

It's highly probably that classes `alert-*` are pre-defined in Jupyter Notebook, but not in Google Colab. I see a simple solution — just define these classes yourself, maybe like this:

```css
.alert {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.alert > h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.alert-info {
  background-color: #1af !important;
  border: 2px solid #04a !important;
}
```

```html
<div role="alert" class="alert alert-info">
  <h3>Note</h3>

  An example of a nicely formatted box
</div>
```

Or maybe change the colors (`1af` etc.).

If you need a better box than the one that appears if you run the above snippet, you may use the style from your first example of a nice box.

*UPDATE*: a box using your style.

```css
.alert {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.alert > h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.alert-info-stylish {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.8) !important;
  background-color: white !important;
  margin-top: 1em !important;
  margin-bottom: 1em !important;
  margin: 1.5625emauto !important;
  padding: 0 .6rem .8rem !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  page-break-inside: avoid !important;
  border-radius: .25rem !important;
  box-shadow:0 .2rem .5rem rgba(0,0,0,.05), 0 0 .05rem rgba(0,0,0,.1) !important; 
  transition: color .25s, background-color .25s, border-color .25s !important;
  border-right: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
  border-left:.2rem solid #007bff80 !important;
}
```

```html
<div role="alert" class="alert alert-info-stylish">
  <h3>Note</h3>

  An example of a nicely formatted box
</div>
```